# How can I use channel send direction in Go

Tags: multithreading, go

In Go, it can be specified which direction a channel can send. I am trying to create an example about it, look at the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    ic_send_only := make(<-chan int) //a channel that can only send data - arrow going out is sending
    ic_recv_only := make(chan<- int) //a channel that can only receive a data - arrow going in is receiving

    go func() {
        ic_recv_only <- 4555
    }()

    go func() {

        ic_send_only <- ic_recv_only

    }()

    fmt.Println(ic_recv_only)
    time.Sleep(10000)

}
```

I get the compiler error

```
# command-line-arguments
.\send_receive.go:19: invalid operation: ic_send_only <- ic_recv_only (send to receive-only type <-chan int)
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 2]
```

How can I use channel direction in the right way?

Or does anyone have a better sample than me?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Three issues:

- You have the send and receive operations reversed (which is the error you're seeing)
- Creating recv-only or send-only channels make no sense, as you cannot use them
- The notation you're using is trying to send the channel itself, not the result. You need to receive *and* send, which requires two arrows.

  `ic_recv_only <- <-ic_send_only`

You may be confused because you have the terminology reversed. `<-ch` is a "receive operation", and `ch <-` is a send operation. Note that in your example, everything would be deadlocked because you can't complete the corresponding sends and receives to pass something through either channel.

Here is a complete example:

```
// This receives an int from a channel. The channel is receive-only
func consumer(ch <-chan int) int {
    return <-ch
}

// This sends an int over a channel. The channel is send-only
func producer(i int, ch chan<- int) {
    ch <- i
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go producer(42, ch)
    result := consumer(ch)
    fmt.Println("received", result)
}
```

Comment: Also `fmt.Println(ic_recv_only)` is probably a mistake.

Comment: Do you have a better sample then my?

Comment: @zero_coding: OK, I think I see what you're looking for. All add an example.

Comment: I'm wondering what is the use of creating a receive-only or send-only channel. I understand the use of creating a bidirectional channel and then make it read or write only by conversion or assignment, when used as function parameter for example. But why when creating it?

Comment: @siritinga: there isn't really a reason to `make` a one-way channel, since you can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

The key point that JimB has made, to summarise, is that

- You create **channels** using `make`
- Every channel has two **ends**.
- You communicate via the **ends** of channels via `<-`. The ends are important.
- There is a **sending end** and a **receiving end**; channels are unidirectional.

Note also that each end can be safely accessed concurrently by more than one goroutine.

Also note that JimB's example `producer(i int, ch chan<- int)` and `consumer(ch <-chan int)` functions have parameters that specify which end they use via `<-chan` and `chan<-`, instead of just `chan`. Although this is optional, it is **good practice** because the compiler will help you fix silly mistakes if you do this.

Comment: Aside: Go did not (alas) use the original CSP notation `?` for receive and `!` for send. Instead it has `<-` for both actions, which IMHO is less clear.